# Navigation Architecture Component: How i can navigate a fragment from the back stack?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

i have two fragments A and B i am using navigation controller to navigate from A To B when i come back to A the navigation controller create another instance of A !! not calling the old instance from the stack and increase the sack size in this case the stack size will be 3 fragments,
how i can fix this issue ?

here is my graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_dest"
app:startDestination="@id/home_dest">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/a_dest"
    android:name="com.intcore.e_commerce.e_commerce.ui.homefragment.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/b_dest"
    android:name="com.intcore.e_commerce.e_commerce.ui.favoritesfragment.FavoritesFragment"
    android:label="@string/favorites"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" /></avigation>
```

and here is my code the i use to navigate.

```
void onAClicked() {
    Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.a_dest);
}


void onBClicked() {
    Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.b_dest);
}
```

Comment: I suppose that `onAClicked` is on B fragment; so why not calling `Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.navHost).navigateUp()` from `onAClicked`?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the action connecting the nav_host_fragment to the a_dest, you need to set the pop behavior to popTo nav_host_fragment inclusive(in the navigation editor).
2. Repeat the same for connecting nav_host_fragment to b_dest.
   PopTo inclusive pops off everything on the back stack including the referenced fragment transaction.
3. Create an action connecting the a_dest to the nav_host_fragment and from b_dest to the nav_host_fragment. For each fragment, Select PopTo nav_host_fragment with the inclusive flag turned off.